# Creating a bootstrap 4 wizard with tabs, but the buttons only work once

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to be able to navigate between tabs.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="divOne" class="tab-pane fade in active show">
            Div One Content
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#divTwo">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div id="divTwo" class="tab-pane fade">
            Div Two Content
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#divOne">Previous</a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

When the page loads, you click the first 'Next' link and it hides the divOne and shows divTwo. When you click Previous, it then hides divTwo and shows divOne.

However after that, clicking Next again nothing happens.

I'm not sure if I've got my markup messed up or if I should be using some kind of jquery to do next/previous.

Comment: Might wanna check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#with-controls)

Comment: because of both the `<a class="nav-link active">` are being active after the first click.

Comment: you can do with JS

Answer (score 0):

You can also doing like that

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="divOne1" class="tab-pane fade show active">1st</div>
    <div id="divTwo1" class="tab-pane fade">2nd</div>
</div>
<nav>
    <div class="nav" id="navClassID">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#divOne1">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#divTwo1">Profile</a>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```